# How to have multiple devices transferring data on different COM ports

Tags: windows, crash, serial-port, ftdi, bsod

I have a Windows program that is collecting tons of data from 5 devices that are connected from Windows through USB, but using a virtual com port with FTDI chip on the device.  So for example I have COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5 that I'm sending data too.  I'm sending tons of data, test is running for 1-7 days with little pausing.

I have found that I'm getting BSOD / PC crashes, usually from the FTDI COM port driver, ftser2k.sys .  I've updated the driver to the latest, and all other drives to the latest.

Originally, I was trying to do 10-15 devices, but that would never work.  With 5 devices, I can get it to work occasionally.  I'm also going through a USB hub.

Any other ideas to solve this instead of reducing number of devices testing in parallel? I would really like to be able to test at least 5 at a time.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your virtual com port software.  I've run 30+ devices on my PC collecting data in parallel from the serialport at high baud rates and 1 second data with no issues.  I used a Serial to USB adapter that used Silicon Labs usb drivers.

Comment: What protocol are you using?  RS-422 and RS-485 are designed for multiple transmitters and multiple receivers.  And RS-232 to RS-85 hardware converters are available for cheap.

Comment: I'm not sure what protocol it would be.  I'm using Windows C# and creating a SerialPort() object. I connect via a virtual com port.  It then travels over a USB cable to go to a FTDI FT2232D chip on my device.